# Accessing to website remote on the private company network with VPN connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, vpn

I have published a new ASP NET C# web site on the private company network.

This new web site works on a windows server 2012 server and this is the [authentication method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.user?view=netframework-4.8) for access to web site :

```
public void Authentication()
{
    string username = Page.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
    string[] strUsername = username.Split('\\');

    if (strUsername.Length > 0)
    {
        username = strUsername[strUsername.Length - 1];
    }
}
```

But I have problem to accessing when I'm connected from my house using **VPN connection**, because the website not validate my access as if not identify the variable :

```
string username = Page.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
```

The access on the private company network is with server proxy, the access on the **VPN connection** don't use server proxy.

The administrator of private company network says it's not a network problem.

I have tried in windows server 2012 server setting IIS property "Authentication" without success.

I verified that when I connect with VPN the user recognized by `Page.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();` is always "administrator" ...

I have tried with **ASP Classic** web page code :

If I connected on the private company network the output is :

```
AUTH_USER: Domain\Username
LOGON_USER: Domain\Username
REMOTE_USER: Domain\Username
```

If I connected with VPN the output is :

```
AUTH_USER: ServerName\administrator
LOGON_USER: ServerName\administrator
REMOTE_USER: ServerName\administrator
```

How to do resolve this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you login to your local system as the same Active Directory account that you login to the VPN using?  Under both circumstances (in the office, and at home on the VPN), what is the output of `whoami`?

Comment: Do you RDP into a server when using the VPN, or do you always do everything locally on your machine that is connected to the VPN?